# Full height for inner div

Tags: html, css, height

See the following image my bottom gray color (**parent div background color**) height increasing with parent div `height`. I wanted full height for description div like first div (`10px` padding for all side).

[image: bottom gray color increasing as per height of parent div]

**What I am trying:**

**Code:**

```css
body,html {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.container
{
 margin: 20px;
 float: left;
}
.mainC{
 width: 150px;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
 background-color: #e7e7e7;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin: 0 5px;
}
.mainC .title{
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: gray;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
}
.mainC .discBody{
 background-color: #ffffff;
 padding: 5px;
 height: 81%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="mainC" style="height:200px;">
  <div class="title">
   <span>Heading</span>
  </div>
  <div class="discBody">
   <p>This is discription part here</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="mainC" style="height:225px;">
  <div class="title">
   <span>Heading</span>
  </div>
  <div class="discBody">
   <p>This is discription part here</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="mainC" style="height:250px;">
  <div class="title">
   <span>Heading</span>
  </div>
  <div class="discBody">
   <p>This is discription part here</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="mainC" style="height:275px;">
  <div class="title">
   <span>Heading</span>
  </div>
  <div class="discBody">
   <p>This is discription part here</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="mainC" style="height:300px;">
  <div class="title">
   <span>Heading</span>
  </div>
  <div class="discBody">
   <p>This is discription part here</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I don't having control on inline style (`height`) of `.mainC`. Inline height may be whatever.

**Question:**  How can I set the proper height of `".discBody"` for all div? for showing padding for `.mainC` is `10px` always.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/jdp09s1c/

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need set height in .mainC?

Comment: Right. If your box heights are actually determined by their content this question changes somewhat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is `.mainC .discBody{height:81%}`, it gets different height for each box, as their parents have different heights. CSS `calc()` could help, [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) IE 9 and up.

```
.mainC .title {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mainC .discBody {
    height: 81%; /* keep this as fallback */
    height: calc(100% - 40px); /* 10px for the spacing */
}
```

Update demo follows, also on http://jsfiddle.net/ptao72w2/1/

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.container {
    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
}
.mainC {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.mainC .title {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mainC .discBody {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 81%;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="mainC" style="height:200px;">
  <div class="title">
   <span>Heading</span>
  </div>
  <div class="discBody">
   <p>This is discription part here</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="mainC" style="height:225px;">
  <div class="title">
   <span>Heading</span>
  </div>
  <div class="discBody">
   <p>This is discription part here</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="mainC" style="height:250px;">
  <div class="title">
   <span>Heading</span>
  </div>
  <div class="discBody">
   <p>This is discription part here</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="mainC" style="height:275px;">
  <div class="title">
   <span>Heading</span>
  </div>
  <div class="discBody">
   <p>This is discription part here</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="mainC" style="height:300px;">
  <div class="title">
   <span>Heading</span>
  </div>
  <div class="discBody">
   <p>This is discription part here</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would opt to change the markup by adding and extra div to achieve this effect.

In the code below I've used an absolutely positioned `div` called `.mainC-inner` inside each of your `.mainC` containers, and changed/moved some styles from `.mainC`.

I've opted to use a border to get the grey outline and white background. This allows you to stretch the new `.mainC-inner` div to the exact height of the `.mainC` parent container, using:

```
.mainC-inner {
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   bottom:0;
   right:0;
   border:10px solid #e7e7e7;
   background: #fff;
}
```

This should work on all browsers, including IE8. Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nrnank32/

```css
    body,html {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .container
    {
        margin: 20px;
        float: left;
    }
    .mainC {
        width: 150px;
        border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
        background-color: #e7e7e7;
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        margin: 0 5px;
    }
    .mainC-inner {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        border:10px solid #e7e7e7;
        background: #fff;
    }
    .mainC .title{
        padding: 5px;
        background-color: gray;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .mainC .discBody{
        background-color: #ffffff;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="mainC" style="height:200px;">
        <div class="mainC-inner">
            <div class="title">
                <span>Heading</span>
            </div>
            <div class="discBody">
                <p>This is discription part here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainC" style="height:225px;">
        <div class="mainC-inner">
                <div class="title">
                        <span>Heading</span>
                </div>
                <div class="discBody">
                        <p>This is discription part here</p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainC" style="height:250px;">
        <div class="mainC-inner">
            <div class="title">
                <span>Heading</span>
            </div>
            <div class="discBody">
                <p>This is discription part here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainC" style="height:275px;">
        <div class="mainC-inner">
            <div class="title">
                <span>Heading</span>
            </div>
            <div class="discBody">
                <p>This is discription part here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainC" style="height:300px;">
        <div class="mainC-inner">
            <div class="title">
                <span>Heading</span>
            </div>
            <div class="discBody">
                <p>This is discription part here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead setting the `height` in `.mainC`, set it in `discBody`.

HTML:

```
<div class="mainC">
    <div class="title">
        <span>Heading</span>
    </div>
    <div class="discBody" style="height:300px;">
        <p>This is discription part here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/jdp09s1c/2/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't difficult if your content determines the box size, and not styles:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.container {
  margin: 20px;
}
.mainC {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.mainC .title {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.mainC .discBody {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mainC">
    <div class="title"> <span>Heading</span>

    </div>
    <div class="discBody">
      <p>This is discription part here This is discription part here This is discription part here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mainC">
    <div class="title"> <span>Heading</span>

    </div>
    <div class="discBody">
      <p>This is discription part here This is discription part here This is discription part here This is discription part here This is discription part here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mainC">
    <div class="title"> <span>Much Much Longer Heading</span>

    </div>
    <div class="discBody">
      <p>This is discription part here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. but I am moving those div within one cylinder which height is not fixed or parallel, so the height of `.mainC` is dynamically changing through my script.